# Running 2 `x-magento-init` scripts in a certain order

Tags: javascript, magento2.2

I have 2 `x-magento-init` coming from different parts of the application and running on the same element (this may not be important).

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "domSelectorHere": {
            "path/to/js": {
                "config": {....}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and in a different template

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "domSelectorHere": {
            "path/to/other-js": {
                "config": {....}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to ensure that the second one `path/to/other-js` is executed after the first one?

Bonus: The first one `path/to/js` may or may not be present in the page.
Is there a way to make sure that if script 1 exists, then script 2 runs after script 1 and if it doesn't exist then script 2 just executes?

I know I can theoretically group them into one single js component but that involves a lot of work.
I'm looking for a lazy approach.

Comment: are the 2 components in different modules?

Comment: @AdrianZ. Yes. And I don't want to make them dependent on each other unless there is no other way\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding the script that should load first as a dependency of the second script? If they fire on the same element I presume they both always fire together, and if script A always has to run before script B this sounds like an ideal case for declaring it as a dependency.

If this will work for you add `path/to/js` as a dependency inside script B's `define/require`.

*Just seen your comment saying you don't want to make them dependent, I'll leave this here though in case it helps others.*

Comment: I will try this. I don't want to make them dependent because theoretically the 2 modules should be able to run separately, but I guess I can use your recommendation as a last resort. Famous last words: "Most probably the 2 modules are always going to be enabled"

Comment: I ended up making them dependent.